# Create an object from an existing object's type?

Tags: c#, activator

So I have an list of objects and I want to loop through them and create a new object of their type based on arguments given to the method. Is there a way to create a new object based on the type of another object?

Context below:

```
private Tile fetchTileByColor(Color c) // color to tile repository fetching
        {
            Tile t;

            for(int x = 0; x < tileRepo.Count; x++)
            {
                if(Art.compareColor(tileRepo[x].id, c))
                {
                    t = (typeof(tileRepo[x]))Activator.CreateInstance(tileRepo[x].GetType()); // <--- Line in question!
                    return t;
                }
            }

            t = (FloorTile)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(FloorTile)); // just fetch a floor tile if we couldn't find anything
            return t;
        }
```

I have an array of types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your method's return type is `Tile` (as shown in your code example), then you have to be able to cast the created object to the `Tile` type to succeed. So just change the cast so that the statement looks like this:

```
t = (Tile)Activator.CreateInstance(tileRepo[x].GetType());
```

Note that this assumes that the objects in `tileRepo` are in fact each an instance of `Tile` or a subclass of `Tile`.

That said, reflection is usually the wrong way to approach problems, and that appears to be the case here. It's not clear from your question why you don't simply return the object you find, nor why you don't seem to care how the object returned is initialized (if you are fetching by color, wouldn't you *at least* want the returned object to have the same color as the one you found?).

If for some reason it doesn't make sense to return the object you found, then you probably should just declare abstract "cloning" method in the `Tile` class and call that. Each sub-class would know how to actually clone the object, copying the appropriate properties from the original to the newly-returned one.

And you certainly don't need Activator to do what essentially amounts to `new FloorTile()` (as in the last statement of your code example).

Answer (score 1):

Your call of `Activator.CreateInstance` is good. However, you cannot cast the result to the result of the `typeof` - it is not going to compile. Good news is that you do not need this cast: `t` is statically typed to `Tile`, so casting to `Tile` will be sufficient:

```
t = (Tile)Activator.CreateInstance(tileRepo[x].GetType());
```